# Python code that stores the distance

Tags: python

```
# Write Python code that stores the distance 
# in meters that light travels in one 
# nanosecond in the variable, nanodistance. 

# These variables are defined for you:

    speed_of_light = 299800000. # meters per second
    nano_per_sec = 1000000000. # 1 billion

# After your code,running
# print nanodistance
# should output 0.2998

# Note that nanodistance must be a decimal number.

# ASSIGN nanodistance BELOW this line
------------------------------------------

    speed_of_light/nano_per_sec = nanodistance

    print nanodistance
```

'Incorrect. There was an error running your code. Check you have no spaces in front of your code on the same line.'

why is this not working?

I think i could do it by, `print nanodistance = 0.2998`

Comment: print nanodistance = speed_of_light / nano_per_sec does not work either but

nanodistance = speed_of_light / nano_per_sec

Comment: Be sure that there are no leading spaces in your instructions, unless they are inside a function definition.

Comment: This looks like homework...

Answer (score 3):

Other way around:

```
nanodistance = speed_of_light / nano_per_sec
```